# Ext4: Prevent "Last mounted" to be stored

Tags: ext4

The Superblock of a filesystem has information when a filesystem was last mounted. You can get this information with `debugfs show_super_stats`

e.g.

```
Last mounted on:          /
...
Last mount time:          Fri Aug  3 10:18:32 2018
Last write time:          Fri Aug  3 10:18:33 2018
```

Is it possible to disable this information to be written to the superblock?
First for privacy, second these stats break the hash of the filesystem, so it is not possible to check if a filesystem was not modified by taking a hash of the filesystem.

Comment: mount as readonly